# Change user column format in Visual Studio TFS Source Control History

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

My company assigns numeric values for usernames in active directory and history window in Visual Studio (for TFS Source Control) displays users in format [Domain][number].

Is there a way to change this to display full user's name or alias?

Answer (score 1):

This is the new behaviour in TFS 2012.  Sadly it is not configurable in earlier versions, I'm not aware of any visual studio addins which can do this either although it would be technically possible to write one.